# Microsoft Word Centering Table Contents

Tags: microsoft-word, text-formatting

For some reason Microsoft Word is doing whatever format it feels like doing. I have a table where the contents of each cell I want centered; the justification/alignment for the contents of each cell should look uniform.  Instead, this is what I'm getting:

Table Contents Alignment Problems:

[image]

In any case, in the table "Layout" tab I selected "Centered" on the "Alignment" box in the Ribbon. The cell contents are just all over the place if you look at columns 1 and 2...some of the cell contents are centered towards the top of the cell, some towards the bottom.

Comment: Check the before and after paragraph spacing.

Comment: @DavidPostill just did.  Looks like both are set to "0".

Answer (score 0):

It is not shown in the screenshot but you may have paragraph marks in those cells. Press Ctrl+* to show formatting marks and remove empty paragraphs if they exist.
If this is not the case try selecting only a few cells in the first column and align them with the button marked in the screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Some things to check for:

- It sounds like you may have already done this, but, just in case… Select the entire table (and/or the full contents of each individual cell) and then click that center option in the *Table Tools > Layout > Alignment* section (highlighted in your screenshot).
- Are there any line-breaks before or after the text in each cell? (E.g., try double-clicking into a cell and placing your cursor at the end of the text, even tapping the right-arrow key a couple of times, and see if there’s any line-breaks or other whitespace you could trim off.) Selecting the Home > Paragraph > ¶ option (or CTRL-* (CTRL-SHIFT-8) as endrju suggested) might help highlight any such cases.
- Are there any paragraph margins on your text that might be pushing the text up or down? (E.g., select some affected text, then select *Home > Paragraph* and try setting the before and after spacings to zero.
- Try clearing all character formatting on all of the table’s text by selecting the entire table’s contents and then *Home > Font > Clear All Formatting* (looks like an 'A' with a little pink eraser).

Hope something in there helps…